# How to customize the Restlet's error message

Tags: customization, restlet

I used Restlet framework to provide the RESTful service.

I used the ResouceException the return the HTTP ERROR CODE, like 400 Bad Request, and so on.

I "new" the ResourceException(code, name, desc, uri) with the code, name and desc. I get the following output:

```
Bad Request  （name）

period is not a number  （desc）

You can get technical details here.  （uri，though I didn't provide it）

Please continue your visit at our home page.    (home page, I didn't provide, too)
```

I think the last two sentences is no use for user to correct the "bad request.".

Can I remove them? How to do?  Or If I want to output sth else, how to customize the message.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the default `StatusService` with one of your own.

Extending the class and Overriding `getRepresentation(Status, Request, Response)` to provide the format you would like.

this can then be set in your `Application` using `setStatusService(StatusService)`

There may be a slightly more up to date way to do this as the method I am using has survived a few Restlet updates, now but it still works.

Update

as of restlet version 2.3.x 
the method to override is `toRepresentation(Status, Request, Response)`

Comment: Why not to implement this in ResourceException or in Status Constructor, I think this will be easy for developer to use it.

Comment: @NingLee I'm not actually a member of the Restlet team rereading I may have given that impression, I have edited it slightly to remove that implication.  Feel free to ask them? But I can't speak for their reasoning.